# creating git repo from existing dir with content

Tags: android, eclipse, git, google-app-engine, github

I have an appengine connected android project, so that the project consists of two directoris: `CatProj` and `CatProj-AppEngine`. Instead of having the two in the eclipse `/workspace` I put them in `cats` directory. Anyway, I create a git account and buy micro level so I can save private projects. Now I am following the instructions for putting my code on GitHub. When I do the following command inside my `cat` directory, I get the following message

```
git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /git_repo/cats/.git/
```

But the thing is the project is not empty: all the code for the app and server are in the directories. The reason I am paying attention to this message is because at the end of the instructions, when I check on github, both directories are there but empty: it does not push the content of `CatProj` or `CatProj-AppEngine`.

The steps I followed are https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'first commit'
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/cats.git
git push origin master
```

When the above failed, I replaced `.` with `*` but I still get the same problem. So I am wondering if there is a recursive command to tell git to commit the recursive content of a directory

Comment: In your last paragraph, what do you mean by "When the above failed"? The `git push origin master` failed? What was the error message?

Comment: I mean that the content of the directories on github is empty, ... so I tried again with `*`

Answer (score 0):

You could check the effect of `git add` by using:

```
man git add

git add [-n] [-v] [--force | -f] [--interactive | -i] [--patch | -p]
             [--edit | -e] [--[no-]all | --[no-]ignore-removal | [--update | -u]]
             [--intent-to-add | -N] [--refresh] [--ignore-errors] [--ignore-missing]
             [--] [<pathspec>...]
```

Also to get some more help on how to use git, i suggest you to check this site: 
http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/

Comment: Thanks, let me take a look.

Answer (score 0):

This should be working..

1. Check whether git is working;
       Try creating test directory and some files with git
2. Ensure to issue commands from git directory;
       use command "pwd"
3. Check for your exclude rules in .gitignore and .git/info/exclude;
       In .git folder

If this is not working try reinstalling git 
-- or --
use TortoiseGit it is GUI application for git
https://tortoisegit.org/download/

Comment: I try creating a README file and it transports fine.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are wondering why `git init` inside a directory full of files tells you:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /git_repo/cats/.git/
```

The directory where you run the command is called the *work tree*, which is different from the *repository*. Your work tree is full of files. But the repository is still empty. Until you add files with `git add` and commit with `git commit`, the repository is empty.

I'm not sure what error you're talking about at the end of your post. After you commit some revisions to your repository, and push them to GitHub, you should see your files and commits on GitHub. The steps you wrote above are correct and should work. If you get an error message, include it in your post.

Btw, it's better to add the `-u` flag to your initial push, like this:

```
git push -u origin master
```

And for your information, `git add .` and `git add *` are different, because `*` normally doesn't include the files starting with a dot. `git add .` will recursively add the current directory (including files starting with `.`), and all subdirectories.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. There are no error messages otherwise. The problem is that when I go to github, the top level directories are there but the files aren't in them. so github has `CatProj` and `CatProj-AppEngine`.

Comment: @learner `git add .` adds everything recursively. Except files that are marked to be ignored, in `.gitignore` or `.git/info/exclude` or global rules. You can see ignored files with `git status --ignored`.